# How to Update the EPSG Database of Gdal on Ubuntu?

Tags: gdal, ubuntu, epsg

I have a Ubuntu 16.04 Server, with `GDAL 2.1.3, released 2017/20/01`.

I need to project a Raster to [EPSG:7755](https://epsg.io/7755) which was added way back in 2016.

When I use this EPSG code with gdalwarp, I get the following error:

```
ERROR 6: EPSG PCS/GCS code 7755 not found in EPSG support files.  Is this a valid
EPSG coordinate system?
ERROR 1: Translating source or target SRS failed:
EPSG:7755
```

How do I Update the EPSG Database of Gdal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't that I know of. It's my understanding that you need to update GDAL to a version that has a newer EPSG database.

- GDAL 2.2 includes [EPSG v 9.0](https://web.archive.org/web/20170608191709/http://www.epsg.org:80/EPSGDataset/WhatIsNew) which was released Dec 2016 so may include
  your EPSG code.
- [GDAL 2.3.0](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/7125) includes [EPSG v 9.2](https://web.archive.org/web/20171209220227/http://www.epsg.org:80/EPSGDataset/WhatIsNew) which was released Oct 2017 so should include your EPSG code.

Comment: I ended up adding the the ubuntugis-unstable repository, and then updated to Gdal 2.2.1, which solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

In current versions of QGIS, EPSG:7755 expands to

```
 +proj=lcc +lat_1=12.472955 +lat_2=35.17280444444444 +lat_0=24 +lon_0=80 +x_0=4000000 +y_0=4000000 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
```

So the easiest way is to define a custom CRS with it, and assign that to your raster.

If you update the csv files from GDAL manually or from different versions, you have to run QGIS crssync to get them into the QGIS srs.db.

Answer (score 0):

On linux, the epsg database is in your system's proj4 folder (for example /usr/share/proj/epsg) as a simple text file.  You can add the appropriate entry in wkt format, providing you have root access.